# Cuando pulso el botón de retroceso o hago el gesto para volver atrás no recarga bien el ViewPager

Tags: android, kotlin, viewpager

Estoy usando Navigation Component, aunque creo que este no es el problema. El caso es que cuando estoy en un fragment que contiene un ViewPager y navego a otro, al volver atrás usando el botón de retroceso o el gesto del móvil, vuelve al fragment anterior pero deja de mostrar el ViewPager. Os dejo mi código de ese fragment:

```
class HomeFragment : Fragment() {

    private lateinit var homeFragmentViewModel: HomeFragmentViewModel

    private var listAdapter: FlagsListAdapter? = null
    private var regionName: String? = null

    private val hashtagLabel: TextView by lazy { home_fragment__label__hashtag }
    private val flagViewPager: ViewPager by lazy { home_fragment__viewpager__countries }
    private val countryLabel: TextView by lazy { home_fragment__label__country_name }
    private val showCasesButton: Button by lazy { home_fragment__button__country_cases }

    companion object {
        fun newInstance(): HomeFragment {
            return HomeFragment()
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false)
    }

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)

        homeFragmentViewModel = ViewModelProvider(this).get(HomeFragmentViewModel::class.java)

        homeFragmentViewModel.getCountriesFlagLiveData().observeOnce(viewLifecycleOwner, Observer {
            setFlagsAdapter(it)
        })

        showCasesButton.setOnClickListener {
            val actionNavigateToShowCasesFragment = HomeFragmentDirections.navigateHomeFragmentToShowCasesFragment()
            regionName?.let { regionName -> actionNavigateToShowCasesFragment.regionName = regionName }
            it.findNavController().navigate(actionNavigateToShowCasesFragment)
        }

        setFormatHashtag()
    }


    private fun setFlagsAdapter(flagModelList: List<FlagModel>) {
        listAdapter = context?.let {
            FlagsListAdapter(
                flagModelList,
                it
            )
        }

        flagViewPager.adapter = listAdapter
        flagViewPager.setPadding(130, 0, 130, 0)

        flagViewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(object : ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {

            override fun onPageScrollStateChanged(state: Int) {
                Toast.makeText(GlobalApplication.getContextFromApplication, "Hola", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }

            override fun onPageScrolled(
                position: Int,
                positionOffset: Float,
                positionOffsetPixels: Int
            ) {
                countryLabel.text = ""
                countryLabel.text = flagModelList[position].regionName
                regionName = flagModelList[position].regionName
            }

            override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
                countryLabel.text = flagModelList[position].regionName            }
        })
    }

    private fun setFormatHashtag() {
        val text = getString(R.string.home_fragment_hashtag)
        val spannableString = SpannableString(text)
        val foregroundColorSpan = context?.let {
            ForegroundColorSpan(ContextCompat.getColor(it, R.color.hashtagColor))
        }
        spannableString.setSpan(foregroundColorSpan, 0, 8, Spanned.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE)

        hashtagLabel.text = spannableString
    }
}
```

Este es mi MainActivity que maneja los fragments y el Bottom Navigation:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private val navigationBottomBar by lazy { activity_main__navigation_view__bottom_bar }

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setUpNavigation()
    }

    private fun setUpNavigation() {
        val navController = Navigation.findNavController(this, R.id.activity_main__graph__nav_host)
        NavigationUI.setupWithNavController(navigationBottomBar, navController)
    }
}
```

Cuando carga el fragment la primera vez se muestra así, que es como debería mostrarse, y si uso la Bottom Navigation View también lo hace bien:

[image]

Pero cuando uso el botón de retroceso del móvil, pasa lo siguiente:

[image]